# How to make a task start right after another one finish in google app engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, task

On taskqueue in gae. 
For example, I have task A, B.
How to ensure that task B starts right after task A finishes.
There could be other tasks, like C, to fix this problem.
Also, 'right after' could be loose to 'after'.

How about a dedicate queue with max_current_requests set to 1?

Comment: That isn't how the task queue works. If you need two tasks to run one immediately after the other, perhaps they should both actually be part of the same task?

Comment: Or maybe task A should explicitly enqueue task B.

Comment: @DanielRoseman That doesn't guarantee B will be next.

Comment: Chaining will work for some use cases, it all depends on the order and dependency of the tasks, vs any other tasks that could be run.  If all must be ordered then you probably need to look at pull queues.

Comment: pull queue may worth a try.

Comment: Please add more detail about the expected result, because answers and comments are based on different assumptions about what may be needed.  Can there ever be other tasks except for an A and a B?  Do you need to avoid executing multiple A tasks before their corresponding B tasks?

Answer (score 2):

If you only have two tasks, you can start task B at the end of task A. For example, a task that updates user scores can start a task to send emails after it finished updating scores.

In this case, you are guaranteed that task B is executed after task A, but there is no guarantee that there is no task C in between them - unless, of course, you don't have task C - or any other tasks - at all.

Answer (score 0):

It seems impossible to guarantee that B will be next.

Comment: Not true if there is only Task A and Task B.  You chain tasks, the very last thing you do in Task A is launch Task B

Comment: I don't know about chaining.  I agree with you that Task A can enqueue Task B, but I also agree with flyingfoxlee and Andrei that if during the execution of Task A, another process enqueues Task C before Task A enqueues Task B, then AppEngine is likely to also dequeue Task C before Task B, which is not the desired sequence, as Daniel and Amber pointed out.

Comment: But the original poster didn't mention Task C, and Task C may not be related or affect the outcomes of Task A and B, so as I said if we are just concentrating on Task A and B you can.

Comment: If you have a Task C that must run A-> B -> C then chain all three. If there is no order dependancy between A->B and C then it doesn't matter

Comment: We're making different assumptions, often a bad idea.  I'll ask flyingfoxlee to explain what "right after" means in this particular question.

Comment: Yeah I agree.  Original question is to vague in terms of use cases.